# How to store sensitive data in database?

Tags: database, spring, database-security

I am about to set up database that will store sensitive data. What should I do, to make sure that data is safe in database?

Comment: Please find Solution already provided http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059761/how-can-i-store-sensitive-data-securely-in-a-mysql-database

Comment: The problem with encryption is that it just moves the problem to how do you keep the encryption key secure and that needs to be answered as well.

Answer (score 0):

A simple encryption algorithm would be goo enough. if  your using a web-server then i suggest using crypto-js that has predefined cipher and decipher methods. you can randomize the keys and store them inside the server if necessary.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js
or
https://github.com/brix/crypto-js

if your going to use a tool then there are hundreds of APIs available to encrypt and decrypt...and this can then be stored in a database.

Hence you have data that even you cannot decipher without running the same key that only the server knows..

Comment: he need solution for spring (Java Framework) not using JS @ShyamRaju

Comment: Please explain how to keep the encryption keys secure, you have just moved the problem.

Comment: encryption key security? try diffie helman algorithm... works like a charm! see the video in the link to understand it.

https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modern-crypt/v/diffie-hellman-key-exchange-part-2